# Set VPN connection on iOS programmatically or openVPN source code

Tags: ios, ios7, configuration-files, vpn, openvpn

I tried to find openVPN source code for iOS, but found only for Android. OpenVPN create app for AppStore in collaboration with Apple or something, so they don't want (or can't) to distribute source codes.

So, I continued searching on this theme and found documentation about Configuration Profile Key ([link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010206)) and found this article ([link](http://jelockwood.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/how-to-do-vpn-on-demand-for-ios-at-zero.html)). But this article says:

> 1. You need to use a supported VPN client which can either be the built-in Cisco IPSec client or a supported SSL VPN client

Is this necessary to use some installing client (like openVPN connect from AppStore)?

Can I configure VPN programmatically from my app? And how (if it possible)?

Thank you for any help you can provide in this situation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can configure VPN programmatically from your IOS app. IOS 8 has added a new framework called network extension framework which provides some API's for developers to configure VPN programatically. Please refer the [this blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20210127000423/https://ramezanpour.net/post/2014/08/03/configure-and-manage-vpn-connections-programmatically-in-ios-8/)

Comment: is it possible in ios7 ?

Comment: No it is not possible. Only from iOS 8 Network Extension Framework has been added.

Comment: I cant find much documentation about OpenVPN and iOS, but found many post that recommend the same post (ramezanpour.net/....) but at this address I only get blank page saying "pageok". Any idea where can I find this post?

Comment: Hey @babasmith: [I just found it by means of wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20170917205226/http://ramezanpour.net/post/2014/08/03/configure-and-manage-vpn-connections-programmatically-in-ios-8/) and [there is another one from the same author](https://web.archive.org/web/20170905011136/http://ramezanpour.net:80/post/2014/10/15/create-an-on-demand-vpn-connection-programmatically-in-ios-8/) that might interest you.

Comment: @ashok link is 404, please add relevant info to your answer in the future.